# How do I force minimum accuracy for PhoneGap GPS Geolocation?

Tags: cordova, geolocation, phonegap

I am building an app that requires somewhat accurate GPS position of the user. Right now I'm using:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess,geolocationError, 
    { maximumAge: 60000, timeout:8000 , enableHighAccuracy: true } );
```

When running the app however, I'm getting `position.coords.accuracy` with a value of `29000` sometimes or higher. This is not acceptable. How can I force a lower (more accurate) GPS position?

It's happening on both iOS and Android.

Note I'm using

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" />
```

Answer (score 4):

The best accurancy can be achieved:

- The lower `maximumAge` is set.
- `timeout` depends on how your app is used (is it a "navi-app" mostly used in cars or is it "jogger-app" mostly used on foot?). Basic rule: the higher `timeout` is set the more time you grant your hardware-gps-chip to request accurate coordinates.
- Of course `enableHighAccuracy` must be set `true` as well.

---

Let me explain the points above in (a little bit) more detail.

When you set `maximumAge` to `0` (Zero) you never get "live"-gps-coordinates (not cached) back, because even most accurate coordinates have got a certain age. It really depends on your app-requirements which brings me to `timeout`.

I would set timeout to 5 secs because most modern devices I have used can get coordinates between 0.5-3 secs. It depens on how quick your app is moved (car, on foot). The quicker the app is moved the less `timeout` has to be set otherwise the app can get too inaccurate coordinates. On the other hand `timeout` must not be set to `0`, because the request would be canceled right now every time and you never get "live"-gps-coordinates back.

---

You can also make your own plugin or fork a project on github for instance to have more control over:

- horizontal/vertical accuracies
- to make sure that the gps-hardware-chip is always used (initialize always Android's `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`). Because even when you set `enableHighAccuracy` to `true` there is no guarantee that the gps-hardware-chip is really used, it's only a "wish" that you tell this plugin to use (if possible) gps-satellites and strongly depends on environmental conditions which brings me to the next paragraph.
- ....

Note that: It is not always possible to request most accurate coordiantes because of bad environmental conditions (street canyon, strong cloudiness etc.). Is is a requirement that your app has to get coordinates everywhere and everytime? Then you have to loosen your accuracy-requirement for sure.

And last but not least, after a successful request you can always check for the coordinate‘s accuracy-attribute that must not exceed a certain threshold (depending on app-requirement) and if it does then make another request like in this example:

```
var threshold = "APP-ACCURANCY-REQUIREMENT-NUMBER-HERE";

function requestLocation(callback) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function (position) {
      console.log(position);
      // Does this position fulfill the ACCURANCY-REQUIREMENT of your app? IF SO THEN STOP REQUESTING OTHERWISE REQUEST AGAIN
      if (position.coords.accuracy < threshold) callback(position);
      else requestLocation(callback);
    }, 
    function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }, 
    {
      maximumAge: 60000,// IS A 1-MINUTE-COORDINATE TOO OLD WHILE DRIVING BY CAR? 130KM/hour -> 36 M/sec
      timeout: 8000 ,// IS A WAITING-TIME OF 8 SECONDS TOO LONG WHILE DRIVING BY CAR? 
      enableHighAccuracy: true // YES, THIS ATTRIBUTE MUST BE SET TO TRUE
    }
  );
}

requestLocation(function (position) {
  // position that has got an accuracy less than ACCURANCY-REQUIREMENT
  console.log('request accurate position', position);
});
```

Hope this "story" helps you and Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. I tried deactivating Wi-Fi and GPS, so I thought it would use mobile data (4G+), but even with 100 seconds it fails. Do you know something about this?

Comment: You are welcome. Sounds like that the phone had no "location-source" around at that moment. As far as I know, the GPS-Symbol (Symbol in your settingbar at the header) represents the whole system-localization, so when it's deactivated no apps should be able to request their position.

Comment: With my test-android-phone (lollipop) there is no option to deactivate wifi and keep mobile-data activated in terms of localization so I guess its the same with your phone. Either way, phones can only localize by using signal-metrics either time-of-arrival (signal propagation time, gps) or received-signal-strength (wifi respectively mobile-data), there is no third option. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realized the GPS-symbol was "localization" in general, silly me. I tried changing the localization mode in settings from "GPS, Wi-Fi and mobile" to "Wi-Fi and mobile" only, then deactivating Wi-Fi, and it works with 4G+ localization (probably a triangulation).

Comment: Ok. Just for information: triangulation is never realized with smartphones, because it is too expensive to build at least three antennas into a phone to check at which angle the three signals are arriving and the much less expensive method received-signal-strength has become much better over the years so there was no need for triangulation anymore with smartphones. Trilateration is another area that is always used by gps/Galileo/beidou/glonass-systems to check the position by using pseudo-ranges.