# What are reliable methods of finding geolocation on a cordova/hybrid app?

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, geolocation, gps

I am building a Cordova app that will run on android and ios (windows phone would be a plus).

I am having trouble finding a reliable way to get the geolocation coordinates of the device.

I have been using this API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

I have also used this Cordova plugin: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/

The plugin says that it is based on the W3C Geolocation API.
I am finding that these are not very robust and reliable ways of getting the location. It's not clear if the libraries eventually interface with the hardware or not.

I wrote a small native Java app that runs on Android and it was able to find my coordinates within 4 seconds. Native apps always interface with the hardware more closely so it makes sense that it would be more robust.

I am not seeing a lot of Cordova plugins that interface with native without going through this W3C API first.

I found some but they are not cross-platform:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-advanced-geolocation

Is it very difficult to write a plugin for just listening to the location updates?

Are there any reliable methods?

Comment: The most sophisticated background location-tracking & geofencing module with battery-conscious motion-detection intelligence for iOS and Android. https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt

Comment: Using a certain plugin/method should always depend on your app-requirements. If your app does not need very exact-coords (so no need for gps) then it does not make sense to use any native coded "hardware-plugin" because you do not have to modify a plugin to request only gps-coords. in this case use a plugin based on the W3C Geolocation API instead. Hope this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46328651/2401386) helps you as well to find suitable coords with a certain method/plugin.